# Collect method return as List<CustomObject>

Tags: java, stream

I am trying to collect the method return as list of Object.

i.e. If I have a method like

```
  public Person doSomething() {
          //definition
  }
```

I want to collect it as

```
List<Person> persons = call doSomething()
```

I can do it something like this

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       persons.add(doSomething());
}
```

Where `length` can be constant and independent attribute **e.g. 5**

Just wondering if there is a better way of doing this with streams

Comment: You have a syntax error in `i < length;` you probably are looking for `i < persons.size()`.

Comment: Hello @GiorgiTsiklauri, thanks for the swift response. persons list is just to hold the Person objects. length is different attribute or constant to loop and store in the list. I hope, I was able to solve your doubt

Comment: In that case, it's always preferable to provide that information as well, otherwise, it's not really intuitive to guess for us *what you mean* in your `length` variable. Most intuitively, it should've been standing for list's size. I actually thought of another point (which you actually have), but it's not obvious from the question. So, please keep this in mind to keep giving the full context when you ask the question.

Comment: Make sense, thanks for the input, updated the question accordingly. Thought it was intuitive because I specified the instantiation of the list in the previous line, but would keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it with streams is

```
List<Person> = Stream.generate(() -> doSomething()).limit(length).collect(toList());
```

Whether or not you consider this "better" is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for something like this only.